# Consider the relation R defined on the set Z of integers as follows x $\sim$ y provided that 8 divides $17x-9y$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the relation R defined on the set $\Bbb Z$ of integers as follows x $\sim$ y provided that 8 divides $17x-9y$

Show R is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb Z$ by showing $ x \sim y$ iff 8|x-y 
This sill show  $x \sim y $ iff $ \equiv y (mod 8) $ a known equivalence relation on $\Bbb Z$.

Ok So i have a few questions. How does tilda ($\sim$) affect this proof?

I think i would start is as followed:

Prove  $ x \sim y$ iff 8|x-y

would it be a good idea to start off using the gcd to prove 8|x-y?

Comment: The tilde doesn't affect the proof. It's just a way to record the relation you're given. You then have to prove it's an equivalence relation.

Comment: I think you are pretty nearly on the right track. I would suggest trying the strategy you proposed and edit the question to let us know where you get stuck (if you do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$ 8 | 17x -9y \implies 8 | 16x + x - y - 8y \implies 8 | x-y $ . So if $ 8| x-y$ is an equivalence relation , then this is also shown.